# What is the status of a shtar signed with a false name?

Tags: halacha, names, legal-documents

If Shimon signs a legal document/shtar in front of a Jewish court and with witnesses, but he signs his name as Levi instead what is the status of the document?

Comment: Why would he do such a thing?

Comment: @Cnsersmoit why does that matter?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps it could be different if he made a mistake (somehow) or if he intentionally signed wrong.